# sort a dictionary by a key from an inner dictionary

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsdictionary

i have a dictionary which i want to sort it according to a key from an inner dictionary. Each key in the super dictionary has a dictionary as value. As an example to illustrate what i'm talking about, here is a super dictionary with inner dictionaries respectively to each key.

```
{
    key1 = {count = 2}, 
    key2 = {count = 1}
}
```

thus the count key has to be the key used for the sorting. For now i know only how to sort arrays and i didn't encounter sorting dictionaries before. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

get the array out of dictionary & sort it

```
NSArray* values = [myDict allValues];
NSArray* sortedValues = [values sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(comparator)];
```

another way to do it to make NSSortDescriptor

```
keyDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"count" ascending:YES] autorelease];
sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:keyDescriptor];
sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

I pulled the code from [Sort Descriptor Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001845-BAJEAIEE). Also, [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) comes into play, in that `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` will send a `valueForKey:` to each element in `myArray`, and then use standard comparators to sort the returned values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
NSDictionary * dict1 = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2], @"count", nil];
NSDictionary * dict2 = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3], @"count", nil];

NSArray * arrayOfDictionaries = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:dict1, dict2, nil];

NSArray * sortedArray = [arrayOfDictionaries sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary * obj1, NSDictionary * obj2) {

    // are points equal?
    if ([obj1[@"count"] intValue] != [obj2[@"count"] intValue]) {

        // points not equal, compare points
        if ([obj1[@"count"] intValue] > [obj2[@"count"] intValue])
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        else
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;

    }
}];
```

Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score -1):

Okay, just to add to what others had posted (Thank you!) i also found my own solution which goes like this:

```
        NSArray *keysByFrequency = [object keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary* obj1, NSDictionary* obj2) {
            return [obj1[@"count"] compare:obj2[@"count"]];
        }];

        NSMutableArray *tags = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i = keysByFrequency.count-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            [tags addObject:@{@"tag" : keysByFrequency[i], @"count" : object[keysByFrequency[i]][@"count"], @"type" : object[keysByFrequency[i]][@"type"]}];
        }
```